# how to enable APplicationGatewayAffinity,ApplicationGatewayAffinityCORS,DtCookie in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

How to enable HttpOnly , secure and samesite attributes to ApplicationGatewayAffinityCORS and ApplicationGatewayAffinity cookie and DtCookie in react/node js?

Comment: go to the settings and enable ApplicationGatewayAffinityCORS and ApplicationGatewayAffinity cookie and DtCookie in react/node js

Comment: can u explain in details,i mean what is the syntax for these cookies

Comment: I was sarcastic, your question doesn't meet any SO requirements... please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: so,here my doubt is howcan i set these cookies in my code with Samesite,HttpOnly,Secure Attributes